# Can you avoid locking by guaranteeing that multiple threads won't access the same memory?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, lock-free

Say I have a large array and I want to process the contents with multiple threads.  If I delegate each thread to a specific section, guaranteeing no overlap, does that eliminate any need for locking, assuming the threads don't access any other memory outside the array?

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
global array[9000000];

do_something(chunk) {
    for (i = chunk.start; i < chunk.end; i++)
        //do something with array
}

main() {
    chunk1 = {start: 0, end: 5000000};
    chunk2 = {start: 5000000, end: 9000000};

    start_thread(thread1, do_something(chunk1));
    start_thread(thread2, do_something(chunk2));

    wait_for_join(thread1);
    wait_for_join(thread2);
    //do something else with the altered array
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In a conforming C++11 compiler this is safe [intro.memory] (§1.7):

> A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal
>   sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having non-zero width. [...] Two
>   threads of execution (1.10) can update and access separate memory
>   locations without interfering with each other.

C11 gives identical guarantees (they even use the same wording) in §3.14.

In a C++03 compiler this is not guaranteed to work by the standard, but it might still work if the compiler provides similar guarantees as an extension.

Comment: Is there a compiler that doesn't provide this behavior in C++03 ? I though that, although it wasn't formalize, it was a pretty common feature on modern hardware...

Comment: It has nothing to do with the hardware. Let's say I want to copy 15 bytes from src to dst. Compiler reads the byte in dst that should stay unchanged, copies 16 bytes using a vector register, writes the one byte back. All while another thread looked at that byte. Your source code didn't access the same code, but the compiled code did. C11 and C++11 won't do this. Remember that different bit fields can count as the same memory.

Answer (score 18):

Yes: if you can guarantee that no two threads will access the same element, then there's no need for any further synchronisation.

There is only a conflict (and therefore a potential data race) if two threads access the same memory location (with at least one of them modifying it) without synchronisation.

(NOTE: this answer is based on the C++11 memory model. I've just noticed that you're also asking about a second language; I believe that C11 specifies a very similar memory model, but can't say for sure that the answer is also valid for C. For older versions of both languages, thread-safety was implementation-dependent.)

Comment: "...if two threads access the same memory location without synchronisation" and one of those accesses is a write.

Comment: @AndrewDurward: Indeed, I simplified slightly. The relevant point for this question is that if they don't access the same location, there can't be a conflict.

Comment: If the 'chunks' overlap on cache lines, then you may encounter reduced performance if two threads are processing items on the same cache line from different CPU cores. For best performance, make the chunk size a multiple of the platform's cache line size and properly aligned. But regardless, no synchronization is needed.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can indeed.

[TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) is a good example.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

You do not even need to guarantee that no two threads **access** the same memory location. All you need to guarantee is that no single thread **modifies** any location that another one accesses (regardless whether that means reading or writing).

Given **either** no concurrent access at all **or** read-only concurrent access, you're good to go without locking.

Comment: A single modifier isn't enough to gurantee safety. A reader, reading data as it's written, may get invalid results.

Comment: @ugoren: RIght. That is why I said "**no** single thread writing". A reader may get incoherent results (though not "garbled", just incoherent, due to how all modern CPUs work, but this is usually bad enough) with a writer. In other words, any number of readers is safe, but no writers (on the same location as a reader).

Answer (score 3):

Important performance issue !

Right, you doesn't need explicit locking, since, as said by others, no memory location is shared.

But you may trigger **implicit hardware synchronization**, since arbitrary chunks are likely to lead cache lines to be shared (not much with the figures used in your example, though). It is known as [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

Higher level approach such as [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) resolves these kinds of issue :

- chunks alignment (and threads numbers) are tuned according to underlying hardware.
- it provides a better control over pool of threads, eg amortizing the cost of thread instantiations.
- it's easier to write, and actually less intrusive.